# How to authenticate endpoint using Jwt and prevent users to use not their data in Spring Boot WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

first of all I am not native speaker so I probably will make a lot of mistakes (So I am saying sorry now).

Ok, let introduce my problem, let's say I have simple RestController class in java:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

// repository autowired


    @GetMapping("/repository/{username}")
    public Flux<Repository> getAllUserRepositories(@PathVariable String username) {
        return repositoryService.getAllUserRepositories(new User(username));
    }


    @PostMapping("/user/login")
    public String login(@RequestBody User user) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(user.getLogin())
                .claim("roles", "user")
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(now))
                .setExpiration(new Date(now + 1000 * 60))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, "secretkey").compact();
    }
}
```

Let's say method login is returning JWT token to authenticate my /repository/{username}. And let's say I have a filter to check token (if is valid, and else things). If I do it, then I secure whole endpoint. But  I want secure it much more, I want to let user with specific username use this {username} endpoint. How can I do this? How can I pass this token into controller? (At this moment it is staying on the filter).

Comment: dont build your own security solution, use the existing ones. Use one of the standards out there.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the jwt field "`aud`" which specifies which audience of your service should respond: you can write the endpoint or any information to differentiate this endpoint.

It is specified in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.3

You can parse the token, check for the url and signature and if it is incorrect return a different `ResponseEntity`